# Is there any way to create rounded corners for SVG ARC?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I would like to create rounded corners for svg arc.

[image]

Here is my code for above arc

```
(function() 
{ 
     var svg = d3.select('#pieChart').append("svg:svg").attr('width', 300).attr('height', 300).attr('fill', '#123456').append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + 300 / 2 + "," + 300 / 2 + ")"); 
     var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(100).outerRadius(140).startAngle(0).endAngle(190 * (Math.PI)/180); 
     svg.append("path").attr('d', arc); 
}());
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your question? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: I m using d3.js to create SVG ARC. Here is my code for above arc
<code>
(function() {
    var svg = d3.select('#pieChart').append("svg:svg")
            .attr('width', 300)
            .attr('height', 300)
            .attr('fill', '#123456')
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 300 / 2 + "," + 300 / 2 + ")");
        
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(100)
            .outerRadius(140)
            .startAngle(0)
            .endAngle(190 * (Math.PI)/180);
    svg.append("path")
            .attr('d', arc);
}());</code>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All you need to do is specify a corner radius. However, `cornerRadius` is only a recent addition to d3, so it won't work in any of the versions currently available in the SO snippet editor.

You can see it working below, using the latest version of d3 imported directly from d3js.org:

```js
(function(theta) { 
  var svg = d3.select('#pieChart')
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr('width', 300)
    .attr('height', 300)
    .attr('fill', '#123456')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 300 / 2 + "," + 300 / 2 + ")"); 
  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
 /*************************************************/
 /* This only works in the latest version (3.5.5) */
    .cornerRadius(20)
 /*************************************************/
    .innerRadius(100)
    .outerRadius(140)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(theta * (Math.PI)/180)
  svg.append("path")
    .attr('d', arc)
}(240));
```

```html
<!-- Import the latest version of d3 directly: -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="pieChart"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add a stroke then you can set the properties appropriately on the stroke to render rounded corners - here's the rough idea:

```
(function() 
{ 
     var svg = d3.select('#pieChart').append("svg:svg").attr('width', 300).attr('height', 300).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + 300 / 2 + "," + 300 / 2 + ")"); 
     var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(100).outerRadius(100).startAngle(0).endAngle(190 * (Math.PI)/180); 
     svg.append("path").attr('stroke-width','60px').attr('stroke-linejoin','round').attr('d', arc).attr('fill', '#123456').attr('stroke','#123456'); 
}());
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fmcftahg/2/)